# ArrayList inside ArrayList - android adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

So, I have Client class, which stores Category ArrayList (Client can have a couple of categories). Each category stores Expense ArrayList. So, every category can have a couple of expenses.

Here is the issue: I want to set adapter for one listView, in which we would print out all of the expenses. I know how to create adapter for one ArrayList, but if we have ArrayList inside ArrayList - then I am lost.

Any tips or tricks you might be able to share with me?

Comment: Do you want to add expenses for a particular category together and then do the same for each category?

Comment: You should not put ListView inside ListView as it may cause some scrolling issue. You can use the code I put as an answer if you use GridView inside AdapterViewFlipper, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) with [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html)

Comment: You may write your own adapter. Extend `BaseAdapter` and implement all methods in it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an adapter inside another adapter. I have used this approach in a dummy project.  I put the following code as a starting point.

```
class Category{ List<Expense> expenseList;    }

//this adapter will be used in Activity
class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category>{
    //your other adapter code here
    ArrayAdapter<Expense> expenseAdtr =new ExpenseAdapter(context, category.getExpenseList());
    expenseListView.setAdapter(expenseAdtr );
    expenseListView.setOnClickListner(....);
}

//this adapter will be used inside CategoryAdapter
class ExpenseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Expense>{
    //your adapter code here, should have no issue here        
}
class MyActivity extends Activity{
    //somewhere onCreate or ..... 
    List<Category> categoryList;
    ArrayAdapter<Category> categoryAdtr =new CategoryAdapter(context, categoryList);
    expenseListView.setAdapter(categoryAdtr);
}
```